# What happens in the brain during mid-life crisis?

Tags: physiology, brain, neurophysiology

I was just told by an elder that [midlife crisis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midlife_crisis) occurs during an adult stage and it is a time whereby an adult starts having several thoughts concerning his/her life. After my [research](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/ask-the-brains-is-the-midlife/), I found out that it claims that midlife crisis is a myth.

**Is this true?**, if not;

**What happens in the brain during such midlife crisis?**

**Can a teen experience midlife crisis?**

Comment: Regarding your second point, what most individuals aged between 6 – puberty experience, is "competence vs. inferiority"

Comment: What research have you done to find an answer? Can you share that with us? Thanks.

Comment: as of todays date, there are 7896 entries for midlife crisis on pubmed. Enjoy your read. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=midlife+crisis